# Using if else statement in renders block in react native

Tags: react-native

This is my render function

```
render () {
    return (
    <CheckoutView>
       <CheckoutActionButton onPress={this.props.navigateSplitTender}><CheckoutActionButtonLabel>Partial Card Payments</CheckoutActionButtonLabel></CheckoutActionButton>
         </CheckoutButtonArea>
         <CheckoutButtonArea>
          {if (this.props.env !== 'Production')   
         <CheckoutActionButton onPress={this.props.navigateMockPayment}><CheckoutActionButtonLabel>Mock Payments</CheckoutActionButtonLabel>}</CheckoutActionButton>}
         </CheckoutButtonArea>
        </CheckoutActionArea>
    </CheckoutView>
    )
}
```

What I am trying to do is if the environment is not Production, I am trying to navigate the mockpayment page. But it is not showing up, where I am getting worng?

Answer (score 0):

i think you might have forgot to close your condition on the if statement
{if (this.props.env !== 'Production')
you need a curly bracket to close everything up

Answer (score 0):

The `<CheckoutActionButton..` is not inside of if block, using shorthand condition is better.

```
render () {
    return (
    <CheckoutView>
       <CheckoutActionButton onPress={this.props.navigateSplitTender}><CheckoutActionButtonLabel>Partial Card Payments</CheckoutActionButtonLabel></CheckoutActionButton>
         </CheckoutButtonArea>
         <CheckoutButtonArea>
          {this.props.env !== 'Production' && <CheckoutActionButton onPress={this.props.navigateMockPayment}><CheckoutActionButtonLabel>Mock Payments</CheckoutActionButtonLabel>}</CheckoutActionButton>}
         </CheckoutButtonArea>
        </CheckoutActionArea>
    </CheckoutView>
    )
}
```

If it's not working. Try to log `this.props.env` to make sure it not `"Production"`